# Is there a way to force function resolution priority in gcc/g++?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, casting, operator-overloading

It's easy to understand why we cannot say:

```
template<class A> class foo 
{
     //stuff
     A& operator[](size_type n);
     operator A*();
     //more stuff
 };

somefooinstance[bar];
```

... We get back "ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for second."

What this means, of course, is that gcc doesn't know if we mean:

```
somefooinstance.operator[](bar);
```

or we mean:

```
(static_cast<A*>(somefooinstance))[bar];
```

Now, ISO C++ says all conversions must be considered, yes? But is there no way to force a selection priority? **attribute** doesn't seem to offer anything helpful.

(Please, no "what are you really trying to do?" answers. Yes, this is a canned example. Uncle Sam doesn't want me cutting and pasting code.)

EDIT:

Someone wanted to see exact code:

```
template<class T, unsigned S> class foo
    {
    private:
        T m_bar[S];

    public:
        inline T& operator[](unsigned s)
        {
            return m_bar[s];
        }

        inline operator T*()
        {
            return m_bar; 
        }

    };

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
      foo<int, 100> test;
      test[31] = 6;
    }
```

yields:

23 : warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:

8 : note: candidate 1: T& foo::operator[](unsigned int) [with T = int, unsigned int S = 100u]

23 : note: candidate 2: operator[](int*, int)

... with no -pedantic required.

Sorry about the canned example. What I meant by no cutting and pasting was not only can I actually not copy and paste, I can't explain what I am trying to do because rules and regulations.

Comment: Not being able to cut & paste code is no excuse for posting something that doesn't demonstrate the error you're referring to, if you can post on SO you can test code online at ideone.com, gcc.godbolt.org, liveworkspace.org etc. -- I _think_ that diagnostic comes from `-pedantic` only

Comment: @JonathanWakely No -pedantic required. See edit.

Comment: That's only a warning, so GCC _does_ know which to pick. But I can't reproduce that warning, which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you can make the conversion operator explicit:

```
explicit operator A*();
```

Then it will only be used in cases like `static_cast<A*>(somefooinstance)`.